# Drop an Index from SQL Server by Object ID

Tags: object, indexing

Using SQL Server 2012 and I have somehow ended up w/ an index named:

```
<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>
```

I'm not sure how or when it happened.  I've tried dropping this index using:

```
DROP INDEX EMAIL_ADDRESS.<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>
```

It won't of course since I receive the expected error message:

```
Incorrect syntax near '<'.
```

Querying the DMV in SQL Server tells me I should drop this index so it's even more frustrating that I cannot.  This has been one of those little things that has gnawed at me for a few years now.  I've looked for answers a few times now over the years.  I've probably poured 4 hours into finding a way to drop an index by something other than name.  Nothing.

Can someone help me?  Running this query:

```
SELECT * FROM SYS.INDEXES WHERE NAME = '<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>'
```

Produces an OBJECT_ID of 281104092.  Is there a way to drop the object using this ID?  There must be, right?  Am I just stuck w/ this crazy index forever?

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete with Database Owner Name. It worked for me.

```
DROP INDEX ccl2.[TBL_HamdunSoft].[<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
Or 
DROP INDEX dbo.[TBL_HamdunSoft].[<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
```